# Ionic 2 Resources | Third Party Libraries

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want a code highlighter for my ionic v2 (rc4) project. I tried [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/) .
As said in [Ionic 2 Resources | Third Party Libraries](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/) , I did the following steps:

npm install [prismjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prismjs)   --save

npm install @types/prismjs --save

then add         import 'prismjs'; in my typescript  file &  In declarations.d.ts `declare module '*';` already is there.
in html

```
<pre><code class="language-javascript">var data = 1;</code></pre>
```

but its not working. Am I missing something? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the css will not get included that way.

Can you try to copy the css of the prismjs library into your assets folder and include it in your index.html?

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, What I did to make it works was include the prism.css into the themes folder then rename it to  prism.scss, and then include it into app.core.scss with this code `@import 'prism';`